# Matlab: implementing sum of exponentials using function handles

Tags: matlab

I need to implement the following formula using function handles in Matlab

[image]

where t is the time vector and n is large. Also, Sk and fk are constant for each k. Any efficient way to implement this is appreciated.

Edit:

For the first harmonic, I could write

```
y=@(t) s(1)*exp(i*2*pi*f(1)*t);
```

However, I can not use this in a for loop to generate f(t). Is there a vector approach for doing this?

Comment: Yes I am aware of that! This is not a HW!

Comment: I edited my post to be more specific.

Comment: "I can not use this in a for loop to generate f(t)" -- why not? Is it the hard-coded `s(1)`? Why not simply do `y=@(t,k) ...`?

Comment: Adding them (function handles) results in an error which says it is not doable. The correct way to add them is something like y3=@(x)(y1(x) + y2(x)). However, as the number of terms gets large, this becomes impractical.

Comment: I thought you wanted to do a loop `r=0; for k=1:N, r=r+f(t,k); end`. If not, what is the point of using a function handle in the first place? Are you looking for a function handle that returns the sum over `k`?

Comment: Yes, I am looking to implement that for loop. However, this loop does not work if f(t,k) is a function handle. The simplest case `@(t) s(1)*exp(i*2*pi*f(1)*t)+ @(t) s(2)*exp(i*2*pi*f(2)*t)` results in error _'Undefined function or method 'plus' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'_

Comment: OK. I see what your problem is now: You're trying to add function handles together, which you cannot do. You should *evaluate* the function, and add the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a data vector `s`, a frequency vector `f` of the same length, and a time vector `t` of a (potentially) different length, you can compute the given equation using

```
result = sum( s(:) .* exp( i*2*pi * f(:) .* t(:).' ), 1 );
```

What is happening here is `s(:)` forces `s` to be a column vector. We make `f` into a column vector in the same way. `t(:).'` is a row vector. MATLAB does implicit singleton expansion, so that `f(:) .* t(:).'` returns a 2D matrix. The other `.*` also does singleton expansion for `s`. Finally `sum(.,1)` sums over the fist dimension, which is over all values of `f`. The result is a row vector of the same length as `t`.

If you need a function handle that computes this, simply turn the one-liner into an anonymous function:

```
y = @(t) sum( s(:) .* exp( i*2*pi * f(:) .* t(:).' ), 1 );
```

This anonymous function will capture `s` and `f` as they exist when defining it. `t` can be supplied later:

```
result = y(t);
```

But do note that `ifft` does the same computation but much more efficiently.

Comment: `t` is not a scalar though for my purpose. As I said in the post it is a time vector, e.g., `t=[0:0.0001:5]`

Comment: Then why do you need a function handle? I don't get it! I also still don't get why `ifft` is not good enough.